# How to fix KeyError for key from control variable get() method

Tags: database, python-3.x, tkinter

The code is supposed to:

- grab value from entry1 widget
- based on this value as the key, look up dictionary values
- display those values in entry2 widget
  PyCharm gives KeyError: ' ' error.

The code doesn't account for the user's input error, i.e. let's assume that value in entry1 widget is a legit myDict key.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')
window.title('test')

def showResult():
    x = var.get()
    message = list(my_Dict[x].values())
    result.set(str(message))

my_Dict= {'A': {'aa': 1}, 'B': {'bb': 2}, 'C': {'cc': 3}}

label = ttk.Label(window, text='Enter here').grid(row=0, column=0)
var = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=var).grid(row=0, column=1)

label = ttk.Label(window, text='"Result here').grid(row=2, column=0)
result = tk.StringVar()
entry2 = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=result).grid(row=2, column=1)

btn = ttk.Button(window, text='SHOW', command=showResult())
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

The idea is that when user types "A" into entry1 and presses the button, 
" 'aa' : 1 "
will appear in the entry2 widget.

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
File "...../test.py", line 10, in showResult
message = list(my_Dict[x].values())
KeyError: ''
```

The same script works just fine outside of Tkinter, so it must be something related to GUI. 
Maybe PyCharm knows that at the time entry1 is empty and thus var = ' ' (and no ' ' key in my_Dict}? IDK...

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')
window.title('test')

def showResult():
    x = var.get()
    message = list(my_Dict[x].values())
    result.set(str(message))

my_Dict= {'A': {'aa': 1}, 'B': {'bb': 2}, 'C': {'cc': 3}}

label = ttk.Label(window, text='Enter here').grid(row=0, column=0)
var = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=var).grid(row=0, column=1)

label = ttk.Label(window, text='"Result here').grid(row=2, column=0)
result = tk.StringVar()
entry2 = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=result).grid(row=2, column=1)

btn = ttk.Button(window, text='SHOW', command=lambda: showResult())
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

The problem was in the showResult() procedure and the declaration of the 'btn' object.
When the btn created the connected slot will called but at this time the var object is an empty string. That will occur a prompt KeyError exception in showResult() at the decleration of the message object.

Use instead a lambda expression or refactor the showResult() like this:

```
def showResult():
    x = var.get()
    if x in my_Dict.keys():
        message = list(my_Dict[x].values())
        result.set(str(message))

btn = ttk.Button(window, text='SHOW', command=showResult)
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you explain the places where you have issues and where you need help in more clear terms? =)

Comment: Thank you, birorichard. Your solution works for immediate problem, so I'll accept it as solved, but the code still sees the input as empty. Looks like the real problem is that the dictionary is not getting read, but this is a separate issue I need to look into.

Comment: Are you trying exactly same code to run or want to use in a different environment?

Comment: @Smith788483 as birorichard said in his answer the button command = showResult not showResult(), showResult without brackets!  The command is the function not the result of the function.  hth